# Reference Request for GB-set theory

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Could anyone give me a reference for a book which has an introduction to set theory from the GB axioms as opposed to ZFC, everything I read seems to just look at things from ZFC (Jech...)

Thanks for any help

Comment: That's a nice question, but I don't recall seeing such reference. Perhaps because when it comes to sets, NGB and ZFC prove the same statements. I wonder, why do you look for such a reference?

Comment: You can read *The Consistency of the Continuum Hypothesis*, by Gödel iteself : it is still available in paperback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "GB" you mean von Neumann--Bernays--Gödel set theory, then Mendelson's *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* develops basic set theory from the NBG axioms.

Comment: Thanks, reading as we speak (type!)

Answer (score 5):

The first half or so of *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* by Melvin Fitting and Raymond Smullyan introduces NBG and uses classes freely in proofs. Also, the book is available as a really cheap Dover print.